# React Native Callback keep reference after app gets killed and restarted

Tags: android, react-native, callback

I have a Native Module for my React Native app.

From React Native, I call a function in this Native Module, it looks like this (on Android):

```
    @ReactMethod
    public void show(
            String targetUrl,
            Callback onFinishCallback
    ) {
      ...
      // start a new activity here
      // Before exiting the activity, I will invoke the onFinishCallback
    }
```

The function works well for most cases, but after the app gets destroyed by Android System (when it is in background for long time), if I pull the app to foreground again, my `new activity` will be recreated, but this time, when exiting the activity, I cannot call the `onFinishCallback` because I cannot keep the reference to this `Callback` object after app restarted.

Is there any way to serialize the `Callback` object? So I can deserialize it when the `new activity` gets recreated and call it consistently.